# Prevent swallowing binding exception in UWP app

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp

I my application i have a property like this in the view model:

```
    private User selectedUser;
    public User SelectedUser
    {
        get { return selectedUser; }
        set
        {
            selectedUser = value;
            var detail = GetUserDetail(selectedUser.ID);
            //do something
        }
    }
```

and in the xaml code this property is boud to the SelectedItem of a ListView:

```html
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding UserList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay}">
...
</ListView>
```

In the SeletedUser setter property if a exception raised when calling the GetUserDetail method, the exception is swallowed by the binding engine.

How can i allow this exception to bubble up and catched in the global exception handler?

Comment: You can either use `x:Bind` or check for errors in your output window.

Comment: @Jessica thanks, I cant use x:Bind because the view model dynamically bound to the page DataContext object, is there a way to do this in Binding expression?

Comment: You should still be able to create a VM property in your page code behind and use that for your xBind.